# Why does decoding base64 string on the form "b'...'" (with the b prefix from Python bytes object) gives unexpected results?

Tags: python, base64

I encountered a weird issue when using Python's `base64.b64decode` function on strings with `b'...'` in them. This is a snippet of the code illustrating the issue.

```
>>> base64.b64encode(b"AAAA")
b'QUFBQQ=='
>>> s1 = "b'QUFBQQ=='"
>>> s2 = "QUFBQQ=="
>>> base64.b64decode(s1)
b'm\x05\x05\x05\x04'
>>> base64.b64decode(s2)
b'AAAA'
```

The result from `base64.b64encode(b"AAAA")` is copied and saved as a string `s1`. I also copy just the bytes (i.e. the characters inside `b'...'`) and save it as a string `s2`. When calling `base64.b64decode` with `s1` I get nonsense, while calling it with `s2` gives the expected result. I suspect the `'` symbol is causing some issues since it's not a valid base 64 symbol.

What is happening in `base64.b64decode(s1)` that gives the weird result?

Comment: `b'QUFBQQ=='` is not the same as  `"b'QUFBQQ=='"`.

Answer (score 1):

When you set

```
s1 = "b'QUFBQQ=='"
```

Then the string includes the b and both single tics. Just get rid of the double quotes:

```
s1 = b'QUFBQQ=='
```

The ‘b’ outside the single quote means to interpret it as a byte literal.